# Javascript - Unable to use Element Id as a String Parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, string

Hey I'm trying to make a function that prints out the last character of the id of the element it's called from. This is simply a test before I move forward with my actual plans but I'm stuck here. The Issue I'm getting is that I get an error saying that my parameter is 'undefined', so there is not value being passed, or the value being passed isn't a string and thus string operations (charAt) won't work on it. I have included code. Thank you.

My webpage have an undertermined amount of modal images which , when clicked, open a slideshow album of images. I got this working for 1 image then realized that to have it work for an undetermined amount of slideshows of undetermined size I should make a function that fills the slideshow div. I planned to have each modal image to have an id of "modal-1, modal-2...etc" and have a bunch of arrays with the images each named similarly "slides_1 ,slides_2...etc" and if the last character of both match up, then it will populate the slideshow with the images in the array. This way If i need to add another modal image all i need to do is give it the appropriate id and add an array of its images.[this is a ,past question which sort of illustrates that larger goal.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47127394/any-ways-to-have-many-different-slideshows-on-a-page-without-a-bunch-of-copied-r)

html:

```
<body id="modal-2" onload="fillSlides(this.id)">

   <h2 id="title" style="text-align:center"></h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img id="modal-1" src="https://www.yosemitehikes.com/images/wallpaper/yosemitehikes.com-bridalveil-winter-1200x800.jpg" style="max-width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1);fillSlides(this.id);" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function fillSlides(modalID){
      var slides_1 = ["Images/LS_01.jpg", "Images/LS_02.jpg", "Images/LS_03.jpg", "Images/LS_04.jpg" ]
      var modalI = modalID;
      var lastCharM = modalI.charAt(modalI.length - 1);

       document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "the last char is" + lastCharM;


    }
```

Comment: You haven't shared what you end-goal is.  It's entirely possible there's a better approach, as relying on parsed strings is often not the best / most reliable approach.  For example, have you considered using a data attribute ?

Comment: I don't know what a data attribute is, sorry I'm new to js. I will add an edit which says my end goal

Comment: A [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) is something that you add to the HTML element, and it can be used to hold information you need.  So, for example, if you're trying to determine which element was clicked, you could store a number in the data attribute rather than append a number to the end of an id.

Comment: hm okay thanks ya I suppose that would work better. I'll try that. Also I have added more explanation to my post

Comment: How would you use a data-attribute? Like if I wanted to print a data-attribute like i'm at the moment trying to print the id's last character how would I do this?

Comment: Here's a simple example:  https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/813aeq1w/

Comment: @devlincarnate Instead of using `document.getElementsByClassName("span");` I think is best to use `document.querySelectorAll('span[data-num]');`. This way you attach the event only to the span that has the attribute data-num.

Comment: I've tried something similar here, why won't it work? 
@devlincarnate  https://jsfiddle.net/pcghdwd6/

Comment: See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net  I've updated your Fiddle so it works:  https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/pcghdwd6/1/

Comment: @kakamg0 : yes, that's a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this using data attributes instead of parsing a string.  This will allow you to use a class instead of id's on your HTML img elements, and then determine which element was clicked on via the data attribute.

**HTML**

```
<img data-num="1" src="https://www.yosemitehikes.com/images/wallpaper/yosemitehikes.com-bridalveil-winter-1200x800.jpg" style="max-width:100%" class="hover-shadow cursor img">
```

**JS**

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("img");

var myFunction = function() {
    var attribute = this.dataset.num;
    //attribute has the data-num value
};

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

I'm also binding the click event in JS rather than an inline `onclick` in order to preserve separation of concerns (not mixing JS and HTML).

Update, in response to comment by kakamg0:

Using `document.querySelectorAll('img[data-num]')` would omit the need to use a class for targeting.

**HTML**

```
<img data-num="1" src="https://www.yosemitehikes.com/images/wallpaper/yosemitehikes.com-bridalveil-winter-1200x800.jpg" style="max-width:100%" class="hover-shadow cursor">
```

**JS**

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-num]');

var myFunction = function() {
    var attribute = this.dataset.num;
    //attribute has the data-num value
};

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, what have I done wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/pcghdwd6/

Comment: @BrownBoii333 : See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468350/javascript-not-running-on-jsfiddle-net) for an explanation.  Here's a working version:    https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/pcghdwd6/1/

Answer (score 4):

The `load` event is actually a `window` event, not actually an event on `body`, so `this` within your `onload`-attribute-style handler text is `window`. To access `body`, use `document.body` instead of `this`:

```
<body id="modal-2" onload="fillSlides(document.body.id)">
```

[Live example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cetadihute/edit?html,output) (since Stack Snippets want to supply the `body` markup for you).

---

In general, I'd recommend avoiding `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers. For one thing, other than methods on the element or (sometimes) it's containing element, the only functions they can call have to be globals, and the global namespace on browsers is already really crowded.

Instead, I'd recommend at least using the `onxyz` *properties* on elements and on window. In this case, that would look like this in your JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = function() { loadSlides(document.body.id); };
```

But even better would be to use modern (DOM2+) event handling via [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (with fallback to Microsoft's proprietary [`attachEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/attachEvent) if you need to support obsolete versions of IE; [details here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799448/157247)):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    loadSlides(document.body.id);
};
```

Comment: I simply put it in the onload to test it but really I want the function to load when it the image is clicked (see edit), sorry I didn't explain better. How do I do that because it isn't working